# Move to the next code line if failed In R

Tags: sql, r, rodbc, sqldf

I don't know how to search it on Google.
I have a code of lines that are independent of each other - suppose one line fails for some reason then the rest of the script does not continue. How do I make it continue?

For example:

```
library(RODBC)
library(sqldf)
myconn<-odbcConnect("production")
```

#line 1:
  sqlQuery(myConn,"exec sp_v_table_1")

#line 2:
  sqlQuery(myConn,"exec sp_v_table_2")

## Failed too because line 1 failed

In addition, how do I know that a certain code line - For example :

```
sqlQuery(myConn,"exec sp_v_table_3")
```

has passed successfully and not failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `try` command.

Normally this will cause an error and prevent code that comes afterwards from running:

```
x <- "a" + 1
y <- 1
y
```

However, if we wrap the part after the assignment operator in `try`, the error prints but code written afterwards can still run:

```
x <- try("a" + 1)
y <- 1
y
```

Note that `x` has class `"try-error"`

```
class(x)
"try-error"
```

Therefore in your example, you could do the following to make sure later lines run whilst still being able to pick up that earlier lines failed:

```
x <- try(sqlQuery(myConn,"exec sp_v_table_3"))
y <- 1
y
class(x)
```

The object `y` will still be created, and the class of `x` will tell you whether `sqlQuery(myConn,"exec sp_v_table_3")` ran successfully or not.

`tryCatch` is in a sense a more flexible version of `try`. `try` will only return class `"try-error"` if an error occurs and allow later lines of code to run, but `tryCatch` will allow you to specify what you want to happen if an error occurs. You could also specify what you want to happen if a `warning` occurs or even if the code runs successfully.

And `purrr::safely` is a wrapper around `tryCatch`. There the action specified upon an error is to return a list with two elements: alternate output (by default `NULL`) and the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You could use tryCatch block, you have a reference [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/error-handling-in-r/)

Here you have an example using it for a request handling:

```
urls <- c(
"http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html",
"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz",


   "xxxxx"
)

readUrl <- function(url) {
    out <- tryCatch(
        {
            # Just to highlight: if you want to use more than one 
            # R expression in the "try" part then you'll have to 
            # use curly brackets.
            # 'tryCatch()' will return the last evaluated expression 
            # in case the "try" part was completed successfully
        message("This is the 'try' part")

        readLines(con=url, warn=FALSE) 
        # The return value of `readLines()` is the actual value 
        # that will be returned in case there is no condition 
        # (e.g. warning or error). 
        # You don't need to state the return value via `return()` as code 
        # in the "try" part is not wrapped insided a function (unlike that
        # for the condition handlers for warnings and error below)
    },
    error=function(cond) {
        message(paste("URL does not seem to exist:", url))
        message("Here's the original error message:")
        message(cond)
        # Choose a return value in case of error
        return(NA)
    },
    warning=function(cond) {
        message(paste("URL caused a warning:", url))
        message("Here's the original warning message:")
        message(cond)
        # Choose a return value in case of warning
        return(NULL)
    },
    finally={
    # NOTE:
    # Here goes everything that should be executed at the end,
    # regardless of success or error.
    # If you want more than one expression to be executed, then you 
    # need to wrap them in curly brackets ({...}); otherwise you could
    # just have written 'finally=<expression>' 
        message(paste("Processed URL:", url))
        message("Some other message at the end")
    }
)    
return(out)
}
```

The source is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r) stackoverflow response, which I obviously recommend you to take look.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to capture the error.
A tool I appreciate for thus purpose is `safely()` from the `purrr`package.

Your wrap a function around your existing function call, that safely returns an output, even when an error occurs.

From the documentation (log() example) :

```
safe_log <- safely(log)
safe_log(10)
#> $result
#> [1] 2.302585
#> 
#> $error
#> NULL
#> 
safe_log("a")
#> $result
#> NULL
#> 
#> $error
#> <simpleError in .Primitive("log")(x, base): non-numeric argument to mathematical function>
#>
```

This returns a list, with a result and an error element.